# Is the Progression of My Progress Saved?

Tags: progress-wars

If I halt my progress for now, and later progress back to progressing, will this progression begin from my last progress, or will all progress progress beyond any further progression before starting over?

What I mean is: Does [Progress Wars](http://progresswars.com/) save my progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  I started playing a game, then closed the tab.  When I returned, I was just as progressed as before.